# Across Row Comparison in R for Large Data Sets

Tags: r, performance, loops, matrix

Let's say I have a data frame with 10 variables and 100 observations generated as follows:

```
set.seed(2)
data<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=10,nrow=100,sample(c(0,1),1000,replace=TRUE)))
```

What is the most efficient way to generate an answer to this question: for each observation, what is the number of the remaining observations that have at least three variables of the same value?

A very non-elegant illustration of how I get AtLeastThree:

```
result<-c()
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  for(j in (i+1):nrow(data)){
   result<-c(result,sum(data[i,]==data[j,])>=3)
  }
data$AtLeastThree[i]<-sum(result)
}
```

This takes an extremely long time run, is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**
Using the method proposed in one of the answers, I am trying to get both sets of code to return the same vector.

Adjusted initial code:

```
set.seed(2)
data<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=10,nrow=100,sample(c(0,1),1000,replace=TRUE)))
head(data)

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  result<-c()
  for(j in (i+1):nrow(data)){
   result<-c(result,sum(data[i,]==data[j,])>=3)
  }
data$AtLeastThree[i]<-sum(result)
}
```

Which returns:

```
92 95 96 95 93 93 92 90 88 90 89 88 87 85 85 83...
```

Using the proposed method:

```
set.seed(2)
data<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=10,nrow=100,sample(c(0,1),1000,replace=TRUE)))
head(data)

res <- c(sapply(seq_len(nrow(data) - 1), function(i) {
  sum(rowSums(
    matrix(
      mapply(`==`, data[i,], data[-(1:i),]),
      nrow = nrow(data) - i, ncol = ncol(data)
    )
  ) >= 3)
}), 0)
```

which returns:

```
92 88 94 95 91 93 84 86 85 88 85 85 85 83 84 80 75 78 80 77 74 73 75 71...
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you illustrate this with, say, a 10x3 example and show and explain the desired result? I don't quite understand, and a 100x10 example is a little big to be really clear.

Comment: Is the output from your double forloop correct? ie.: `79, 167, 261, ... 4686, NA`

Comment: The loop is implemented incorrectly. Starting at `i = 2`, the `AtLeastThree` column is being included in the `data[i,]==data[j,]` comparison.

Answer (score 2):

This returns a vector of the number of following rows that match at least 3 of the values:

```r
res <- c(sapply(seq_len(nrow(data) - 1), function(i) {
  sum(rowSums(
    matrix(
      mapply(`==`, data[i,], data[-(1:i),]),
      nrow = nrow(data) - i, ncol = ncol(data)
    )
  ) >= 3)
}), 0)
res
#  [1] 92 88 94 95 91 93 84 86 85 88 85 85 85 83 84 80 75 78 80 77 74 73 75 71 71
# [26] 70 72 67 68 67 66 65 65 62 65 59 63 59 57 56 53 54 56 54 51 49 52 48 47 49
# [51] 48 45 41 42 42 42 40 37 41 36 34 37 35 35 32 32 32 31 29 29 28 26 26 24 25
# [76] 22 23 22 20 17 17 18 16 16 14 12 12 12 10  9  9  8  7  6  5  3  3  2  1  0
```

I add the literal `0` at the end because we don't need to check if the last row has any rows beyond it.

Let's look at the last five rows for quick verification:

```r
tail(data, n = 5)
#     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# 96   1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1
# 97   0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0   0
# 98   0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1   0
# 99   0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0   1
# 100  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   0
```

```
data[96,] == data[97,]
#       X1    X2   X3   X4    X5   X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
# 96 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
data[96,] == data[98,]
#       X1    X2    X3    X4   X5   X6    X7    X8   X9   X10
# 96 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
data[96,] == data[99,]
#       X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9  X10
# 96 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
data[96,] == data[100,]
#      X1    X2   X3    X4    X5   X6   X7   X8   X9   X10
# 96 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

When compared with row 96, the rows that follow have 3, 3, 1, and 6 columns in common, which means 3 of the next four rows have 3 or more values in common, which corresponds to `res[96]`.

Comment: Their forloop returns different result?

Comment: @zx8754, we can look at `diff(data$AtLeastThree)` and see that they are the same.

Comment: Thank you for this, I think I am close to understanding this, could you please have a look at my edit and let me know where am I going wrong?

Comment: *"for each observation" for me means that the number identified to a row counts how many rows beyond it have 3 or more common values, but in your answer the numbers are cumulative. I think you need to reset `result <- 0` in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop solution doesn't appear to be doing what you intend. Notice that the first time the outer loop gets to `data$AtLeastThree[i]<-sum(result)`, every value in the `AtLeastThree` column is set to 92, and then that column is included in the comparison when trying to determine which subsequent rows have at least three values the same.

There are a number of ways to correct for this in the loop approach, but for a binary matrix, matrix multiplication will be much faster. As a function:

```
library(Matrix)

f2 <- function(data) {
  m <- as.matrix(data)
  x <- m %*% t(1 - m)
  data$AtLeastThree <- colSums(tril(x + t(x) <= ncol(data) - 3, -1))
  data
}
```

Benchmark this function against @r2evan's `mapply` solution:

```
f1 <- function(data) {
  data$AtLeastThree <- c(sapply(seq_len(nrow(data) - 1), function(i) {
    sum(rowSums(
      matrix(
        mapply(`==`, data[i,], data[-(1:i),]),
        nrow = nrow(data) - i, ncol = ncol(data)
      )
    ) >= 3)
  }), 0)
  
  data
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(data),
  f2 = f2(data),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>    f1 20729.3 21393.85 22906.539 21989.70 24672.50 31343.6   100
#>    f2   179.0   201.25   367.362   264.05   279.05 11732.3   100
```

For smaller matrices, matrix multiplication is much faster than `mapply`. Note, however, that it will run into memory issues with a large number of rows (for me at ~50K).

---

### Details on the algorithm

To illustrate how we get the desired result from matrix multiplication, look at just the first 10 rows of `data`.

```
m <- as.matrix(data)[1:10,]
m
#>       X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#>  [1,]  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
#>  [2,]  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0   1
#>  [3,]  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
#>  [4,]  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1   1
#>  [5,]  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   0
#>  [6,]  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1   1
#>  [7,]  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#>  [8,]  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
#>  [9,]  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> [10,]  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0   1
x <- m %*% t(1 - m)
x
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    0    2    4    2    3    2    1    4    3     2
#>  [2,]    1    0    3    2    3    2    0    3    2     1
#>  [3,]    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    2     0
#>  [4,]    2    3    3    0    3    0    1    4    2     1
#>  [5,]    2    3    3    2    0    2    2    4    2     3
#>  [6,]    2    3    3    0    3    0    1    4    2     1
#>  [7,]    2    2    5    2    4    2    0    5    2     2
#>  [8,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1     0
#>  [9,]    3    3    5    2    3    2    1    5    0     3
#> [10,]    2    2    3    1    4    1    1    4    3     0
```

In the resulting matrix, `x[i, j]` corresponds to `sum(m[i,] == 1 & m[j,] == 0)`, so `t(x) + x` gives the number of *unequal* elements in each row-wise comparison. To get the desired result, simply compare the lower triangle of `t(x) + x` to `ncol(data) - 3` and take the column sums.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `tapply` + `rowSums` might help as well to boost the speed

```
f3 <- function(data) {
    d <- as.matrix(data)
    n <- nrow(d)
    p <- rep.int(1:(n - 1), (n - 1):1)
    q <- sequence((n - 1):1, 2:n)
    data$AtLeastThree <- c(tapply(rowSums(d[p, ] == d[q, ]) >= 3, p, sum), 0)
    data
}
```

## Benchmarking

```
library(Matrix)

f1 <- function(data) {
    data$AtLeastThree <- c(sapply(seq_len(nrow(data) - 1), function(i) {
        sum(rowSums(
            matrix(
                mapply(`==`, data[i, ], data[-(1:i), ]),
                nrow = nrow(data) - i, ncol = ncol(data)
            )
        ) >= 3)
    }), 0)

    data
}

f2 <- function(data) {
    m <- as.matrix(data)
    x <- m %*% t(1 - m)
    data$AtLeastThree <- colSums(tril(x + t(x) <= ncol(data) - 3, -1))
    data
}

f3 <- function(data) {
    d <- as.matrix(data)
    n <- nrow(d)
    p <- rep.int(1:(n - 1), (n - 1):1)
    q <- sequence((n - 1):1, 2:n)
    data$AtLeastThree <- c(tapply(rowSums(d[p, ] == d[q, ]) >= 3, p, sum), 0)
    data
}

microbenchmark(
    f1 = f1(data),
    f2 = f2(data),
    f3 = f3(data),
    check = "equal"
)
```

shows

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
   f1 20447.3 21722.75 24278.748 22523.65 26020.25 37865.2   100
   f2   181.7   234.90   329.679   281.40   312.80  4800.5   100
   f3   667.4   718.85   819.208   796.85   848.40  1386.5   100
```